# why hashing collections needs to be resized on reaching loadfactor and why can't we wait till the collection is full

Tags: java, hashmap, hash

List multiplies when its full, but hashmap/hashtable multiplies when it reaches loadfactor, so why can't hashmap wait for resizing till its full, is it parting of underlying hasing algorithm??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a big difference between an array-list and a hash-map: the former stores each entry into discrete slots, while the latter may put more than one entry into a slot if the entries' hashes match.  That means that a hash-map may start to slow down long before every slot is taken and indeed, it's quite unlikely that you'd fill every slot once and once only before having to double-up in a slot.

If you've got a fixed set of things that can be hashed, it is possible to create a hash and from it a hash-map that will store just that fixed set of things in an efficient manner: the result is called a [perfect hash](http://www.burtleburtle.net/bob/hash/perfect.html).

Answer (score 3):

Because the probability of hash collisions rises dramatically towards the end of it's capacity (there's just not enough empty buckets). As more entries end up in same buckets, the effiectiveness of queries is diminished long before it's full. Depending on the hashing algorithm, the optimal load factor may vary.

The effectiveness of queries on arrays is not affected by it's load factor, that's why it makes no sense to resize earlier.

Answer (score 1):

An arraylist always puts new elements in the next free slot, there's no need to expand until that slot is taken unless you want to save time in the future - in which case you can use `ensureCapacity`.

A hashmap on the other hand calculates an integer value for each object you put into it. Based on this value the object is stored in a particular bucket - this is done to support fast look-ups. However, the calculated value is not necessarily unique, and even if it was two different values might point at the same bucket. This is especially common for small amounts of buckets and is ridiculously likely to happen if your buckets are almost full.

Consider a hashmap which stored people in buckets based on their birthday. Even with 365 buckets, with 10 people there's roughly 10% chance that you would have a collision. With 23 there's a *50%* chance (more [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem)).

Now, a single collision isn't a big deal, but when you use a hashmap you typically do it for the fast lookups. If several items are in the same bucket, the time it takes to perform a lookup grows longer and longer. Therefore, for performance reasons, you want to increase the number of buckets in order to decrease the density of your elements.